# Troubles with Batch Variables

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble setting an unset variable to a variable.
It is not in a block, and setlocal enabledelayedexpansion is not on, because I like using exclamation marks.

```
cls
IF "%croptomatoes%"=="" set "%croptomatoes%"=="0"
echo Your Hunger- %hunger%/%maxhunger%
echo 1) Eat 6 Tomatoes - 1 Hunger - You have %croptomatoes%
```

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing the `set` syntax with variable expansion and comparison operator.  To set the variable, you do this:

```
set croptomatoes=0
```

Comment: If you get confused in future, remember in WIndows you can generally pass `/?` to these commands.  So, `set /?` will give you information about usage.  Same with `if`, `for` and others.